# EF - Cannot apply operator '==' to operands of type 'TId' and 'TId'

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics

I have this generic class, which uses Entity Framework 6.x.

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity, TId> where TEntity, class, IIdentifyable<TId>
{
    public virtual TEntity GetById(TId id)
    {
        using (var context = new DbContext())
        {
            var dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
            var currentItem = dbSet.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
            return currentItem;
        }
    }

    public virtual bool Exists(TId id)
    {
        using (var context = new DbContext())
        {
            var dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
            var exists = dbSet.Any(x => x.Id == id);
            return exists ;
        }
    }
}
```

And these interfaces:

```
public interface IIdentifyable : IIdentifyable<int>
{
}

public interface IIdentifyable<out TId>
{
    TId Id { get; }
}
```

And entities that looks like this:

```
public class CustomerEntity : IIdentifyable<int>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get;set; }
}

public class ProductEntity : IIdentifyable<Guid>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Guid Id { get;set; }
}
```

**My issue is that it doesn't compile. I get this error:**

> Cannot apply operator '`==`' to operands of type '`TId`' and '`TId`'

I tried to change it to `x => Equals(x.Id, id)`, but then EF cannot translate it. Any way around it?

I know that I can use `Find()` instead of `FirstOrDefault`. But I need this for more than the methods mentioned above. **Is there any way I can let EF compare `TId` with `TId`?** `TId` is currently only `guid` and `int`. I've already seen the questions below, but they don't handle the issue regarding translation to SQL.

[Can't operator == be applied to generic types in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390900/cant-operator-be-applied-to-generic-types-in-c)

[How to solve Operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'T'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8982645/how-to-solve-operator-cannot-be-applied-to-operands-of-type-t-and-t)

Comment: So from the answers you linked why didn't you set TId : class? TId is either class or struct and c# can't tell

Comment: @misha130 - Because `int` isn't a `class`.

Comment: Int is a class called Int32 in c#

Comment: @misha130 It is not, it is a struct called `Int32`

Comment: Yes, Magnus is right, and even  if I add the `struct` constraint it will not compile.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Update:** Here is a simple concise way that works with EF.

Add the following constraint to the `GenericRepository` class

```
where TId : IEquatable<TId>
```

and then use `Equals` method

```
x => x.Id.Equals(id);
```

---

**Original answer:**

This is a known issue with generics which normally is handled by using `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` instead of the `==` operator. However this approach doesn't work with LINQ to Entities.

One way to solve it is to build the predicate dynamically using the [`Expression`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression(v=vs.110).aspx) class from the `System.Linq.Expressions` namespace like this:

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity, TId> where TEntity: class, IIdentifyable<TId>
{
    protected static Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> EqualsPredicate(TId id)
    {
        Expression<Func<TEntity, TId>> selector = x => x.Id;
        Expression<Func<TId>> closure = () => id;
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(
            Expression.Equal(selector.Body, closure.Body),
            selector.Parameters);
    }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
dbSet.FirstOrDefault(EqualsPredicate(id));
```

or

```
dbSet.Any(EqualsPredicate(id));
```

etc.

Comment: When you say 'this is a known issue', do you have any reference?

Comment: @HANDL Well, it's known to everyone trying it because of the compiler error :) And the reason is because `==` operator is not defined for every type - sort of explained in the [Compiler Error CS0019 documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0019). And the lack of generic operator constraint. But you are right, probably I've used incorrect wording.

Comment: Nothing wrong with your wording, it's just that I've asked a similar question because I couldn't believe this wasn't working. But Eric Lippert already formulated this in an acceptable [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46895752/1300910).

Comment: The very concise solution in the 'update' is definitive and should be highlighted over and above the original answer text. It's a very good and simple solution!

Answer (score -1):

This only compiles if you constrain the `TId` type to be a reference type:

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity, TId> 
    where TEntity: class, IIdentifyable<TId> 
    where TId: class
```

However, this may not be suitable in your case, so you would have to create different classes to support GUID, int or long id values.

Comment: Thank you. This would indeed solve the issue. But since I actually want to use `int` as Id it will be problematic to implement.

Answer (score -1):

It's because you can not compare generic type with generic type by == operator. Instead use Equals operator
in your code :

```
 public virtual TEntity GetById(TId id)
{
    using (var context = new DbContext())
    {
        var dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
        var currentItem = dbSet.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id.Equals(id));
        return currentItem;
    }
}
```