# Check if value is 0 with extension method

Tags: c#

I have an extension method which looks like

```
public static T ThrowIfObjectIsNull<T>(this T argument) where T : class
{
  if (argument == null)
      throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(argument));

   return argument;
}
```

This basically check if the object that's being passed isn't null. What I am trying to do is create another extension method where the `int` value which is being passed in isn't 0. So I have gone ahead and created:

```
public static T ThrowIfZero<T>(this T argument) where T : struct
{
   if (argument == 0)
     throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("some error here");

   return argument;
}
```

Of course the above does not compile suggesting the error:

> Error CS0019  Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'int'

Can someone point me to the right direction on how I would check if the argument value isn't `0`?

Comment: Why is it generic at all? Just use `int`. But then again, why even have an extension method at all?

Comment: `if (argument == default(T))`

Comment: Why not just `public static int ThrowIfZero(this int argument) { ... }` ?

Comment: You can't do `==` comparison for generic struct values. so `if (argument == default(T))` doesn't compile.

Comment: @DmitryPavliv care to make that an answer? (btw, it could work for value types and reference types in a single method...)

Comment: Also, your extension methods lose the context so when you use `nameof`, it's completely unrelated.

Comment: Why not simply `argument.Equals(default(T))` with `where T : struct` constraint ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could simply use `Equals`:

```
public static T ThrowIfZero<T>(this T argument) where T : struct
{
    if (argument.Equals(0))
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("some error here");

    return argument;
}
```

But that will not really work well if the argument is for example a decimal `0.0m` which is not equal to the integer `0` as Peter has commented correctly.

So if you want a version that works for any number you could use this approach:

```
public static T ThrowIfZero<T>(this T argument) where T : struct
{
    bool isZero = Decimal.Compare(0.0m, Convert.ToDecimal(argument)) == 0;
    if (isZero)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("some error here");

    return argument;
}
```

Comment: or `IEquatable<T>`, and I'm not sure you need the cast, `argument.CompareTo(0)` should compile just fine.

Comment: Thanks for this, I will have a go at it and let you know how I get on

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen: or simply using `Equals` without additional constraint :)

Comment: @TimSchmelter Ah ok... I wonder what is the point of checking for example whether the `DateTime` struct is 0 though ?

Comment: @Fabjan: OP didn't want to use it for DateTime. You could use it with it though, but it would not throw an exception because a DateTime is never 0

Comment: This solution will only really work for `int`. With `0L` or `0.0` the `CompareTo(0)` version will throw a runtime error because `0` is not of type `Int64` or `Double`. In the `Equals(0)` version the type of `0L` or `0.0` is not the type of `0` and therefor argument is not treated as equal to `0` and the exception is not thrown. In the end this is not better than adding an `int` type constraint to `T`.

Comment: @PetervanderHeijden: fixed

Answer (score 12):

You can use [EqualityComparer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224763(v=vs.110).aspx) as well.

```
public static T ThrowIfZero<T>(this T argument) where T : struct
{   
     if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(argument, default(T)))   
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("some error here");

     return argument;
}
```

You can refer answer of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8982645/how-to-solve-operator-cannot-be-applied-to-operands-of-type-t-and-t) (credit should go to @Mehrdad).

Comment: This sounds like the better solution. It can also handle zeros on custom structs.

Comment: @ArturoTorresSánchez: but that was not a requirement. Why `ThrowIfZero` should throw an exception with non-zero values, for example if you pass `new DateTime()`? Neither OP wanted this nor the name of the method suggests that it behaves like that. If i needed a `ThrowIfDefault` i'd use this.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn’t look like you need generics at all. If the variable is just an int as you suggest, just use:

```
public static int ThrowIfZero(this int argument)
{
    if (argument == 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("some error here");
    }

    return argument;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`int`, `decimal` etc. implement [`IComparable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable(v=vs.110).aspx) so something like this also works:

```
public static T ThrowIfZero<T>(this T argument) 
    where T : struct, IComparable
{
   if (argument.CompareTo(default(T)) == 0)
     throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("some error here");

   return argument;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way I saw recently:

```
public static int ThrowIfZero<T>(this T param)
    where T : struct
{
    var o = (object)param;
    int i;

    try   { i = (int)o; }
    catch { throw new ArgumentException("Param must be of type int");  }

    if (i == 0) throw new ArgumentException("Must be not be zero");

    return (int)(object)param;
}
```

We can trick the compiler into letting us cast `T` into `int` by casting it to `object` first. This works fine for `int`, but the downside is this only works for `int`, and won't work for a `float`.

If you want it to work with all numerable types, you can use pattern matching and do something like this:

```
public static T ThrowIfZero<T>(this T param)
    where T : struct
{
    switch (param)
    {
        case int     i:  if (i == 0)  throwException(); break;
        case double  d:  if (d == 0)  throwException(); break;
        case float   f:  if (f == 0)  throwException(); break;
        case decimal c:  if (c == 0)  throwException(); break;
        case long    l:  if (l == 0)  throwException(); break;
        case uint    ui: if (ui == 0) throwException(); break;
        case ulong   ul: if (ul == 0) throwException(); break;
        case byte    b:  if (b == 0)  throwException(); break;
        default: throw new ArgumentException("Invalid Type");
    }

    return param;

    // ---- Local Functions ---- //
    void throwException() => throw new ArgumentException("Must not be zero");
}
```

Of course, the best solution would be if they took Jon Skeet up on his offer and did a `where T : numeric` that constraints it to basically the types above, and maybe some custom types too, so we could include our own `ComplexNumber` or `SuperBigInteger`.

To be honest, I wouldn't do it either of these ways, because the first way has casting, and the second way just leads to missing cases and having to maintain the `switch` if you need, just thought I'd show the more options, though.