# How to apply == to generic types - data types like string or int in C#

Tags: c#, generics, linq-to-sql

I have the following generic classes:

```cs
public class Entity<Key>
{
    public Key ID;
}

public interface IEntity<T>
{
    T ID { get; set; }
}

public class GenericRepo<TEntity,CEntity,Key>
    where TEntity : class, IEntity<Key>
    where CEntity : class, IEntity<Key>
{
    protected readonly DataContext _context;
    protected readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public GenericRepo(DataContext context, IMapper mapper)
    {
        _context = context;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

    public CEntity GetByID(Key id)
    {
        //here i get operators == cannot be applied to operands of type 'Key' and 'Key'
        TEntity dbEntity = _context.Set<TEntity>().FirstOrDefault(e => e.ID == id);

        if (dbEntity == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return _mapper.Map<CEntity>(dbEntity);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to pass a generic type `Key` to the `ID` property. I'm getting `operators == cannot be applied to operands of type 'Key' and 'Key'` when I use `==` on the passed parameter and the Set's property which is also of type `Key`, since they are the same generic type `Key`, how can I implement equality on `Key` on these classes?

the types that I need to pass are `int` or `string`.

However, I tried adding a `where` clause to the class `where T : Type`, the operands error removed, but now I cant pass neither `string` or `int` like the following `Entity<int>` i get `there is no boxing conversion from int to System.Type`.

I saw some answers like using `.Equals` and implementing IComparer to classes, but in my case its a type, and I need `==` to use it in LINQ to SQL in ef-core.

Is there any `where` condition to add to the class that I can pass a type to my class and use `==` or any other way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't operator == be applied to generic types in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390900/cant-operator-be-applied-to-generic-types-in-c)

Comment: @WaiHaLee I saw that, almost all answers use `EqualityComparer`, i was hoping to find a way to pass `string` or `int` and compare them with `==` without having to go through IComparer or similar interfaces

Comment: This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8982693/7086678) maybe helpful for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up using a simple `.Equals()`

```cs
TDataSet dbEntity = _context.Set<TDataSet>().FirstOrDefault(e => e.ID.Equals(id));
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to apply == to generic types

You do not. It is a weakness so to say of the .NET type system that generics can not handle operations as operations are defined via static methods.

You pretty much HAVE to go through IComparable or a similar interface.